# Angular 4 NgModel not binding data

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-ngmodel, angularfire2

NgModel is not working on this component. I already imported FormsModule and stuff. Other features like * ngIf and angled * ngFor are working well on other components. Check out the app.module as well.

Help!

I'm using firebase and angularfire2 for this.

My component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { Rating } from '../rating';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/SwitchMap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-view-rating',
    templateUrl: './view-rating.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./view-rating.component.css']
})

export class ViewRatingComponent implements OnInit {

    name: any;
    rating: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
    user: firebase.User;
    item: any;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private afAut: AngularFireAuth,
        private afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
            this.afAut.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
                this.user = auth;
            })
        }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('item');
        this.rating = this.afDb.object(this.user.uid + '/' + this.name);
        console.log(this.rating)
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```js
<div class="form-container">

    <div *ngIf="rating" >
        <input [(ngModel)]="rating.name" name="name" >
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in the browser console?

Comment: @Aravind no, the console don't show nothing

Comment: @Aravind I've tried this without success but tried again and now it works! Was a simple mistake. I'm new to the angular. thank you so much.

Comment: what was the mistake?

Comment: @Aravind I tried to subscribe before getting the expected object from database

Comment: upvote the answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rating` is of type `observable` how will you use it for `ngModel`. you need to subscribe to it and assign to some other object and use that object as `ngModel`

Declare a object of type any and not observable as below,

```
ratingObject:any;

this.rating = this.afDb.object(this.user.uid + '/' + this.name);
this.rating.subscribe(data =>{
        this.ratingObject = data;
});
```

and then use in the HTML as below,

```
<div *ngIf="ratingObject" >
    <input [(ngModel)]="ratingObject.name" name="name" >
</div>
```